# How to keep the DropDown list opened after PostBack in ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDown like below:-

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox" runat="server"  EmptyMessage="Select"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" ShowMoreResultsBox="true" EnableVirtualScrolling="true" HighlightTemplatedItems="true" ItemsPerRequest="10" >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table style="width: 500px">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 400px"><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Font-Bold="true" Text="Name" OnClick="LB_Click" ></asp:LinkButton></td>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 100px">ID</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table style="width: 500px">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 400px"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name")%></td>
                            <td style="width: 100px"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
            <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlConnectionString %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM table1 order by name asc" />
```

When I run the application and click on the RadComboBox, then the DropDown `List` opens and shows the items in the  DropDown list.

Now when I click `LinkButton1` (i.e `Name`) there is a PostBack of the page, then the opened DropDown list closes automatically and again I have to click on my `RadComboBox` to open the DropDown list,

Is there a way  to keep the DropDown list opened, after the postback of the page ?

Could anyone please help .  ThankYou.

Comment: No, as far as I know it is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I too think so ! ThankYou.

Comment: @VDWWD But i think we can handle it by calling a javascript from code !!